# Security implications of Linux perf event paranoia setting

Tags: linux, security, perf

I want to use Linux Perf infrastructure to collect performance metrics
of applications through the PAPI interface[1]. As I am interested also
in un-core events, I will need perf paranoia settings set to -1, i.e.

```
echo "-1" > /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid
```

However, the administrators of my "local" cluster are reluctant to do
so, fearing that the setting "-1" will potentially allow users to read
out memory regions containing sensitive data such as credentials
(password, ssh-keys) of the root user.
(Note, that the compute nodes are never shared between users and
rebooted between jobs, so only root is exposed.)

I would like to understand the real risks of this setting. I am aware of
the document "Perf events and tool security" [2], but honestly do not
have the skill to assess the implications for root credentials from it.

Any sketch of an argumentation line to convince my admins is also very
much appreciated.

Comment: I *think* the main risk is exposing kernel ASLR via addresses of `perf record` events in kernel space, which would make other exploits easier if there were any.  I don't think it directly breaks security, if you still have mitigation enabled for vulnerabilities like Meltdown.

Comment: FWIW, the [msr-safe](https://github.com/LLNL/msr-safe) kernel module was designed to provide whitelisted access to such data in restrictive environments. [variorum](https://github.com/LLNL/variorum) as a library may provide more abstract access.